# How can I align div bellow off my navbar?

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment

I have a layout with a navbar and 4 divs. The first div are cropped by navbar. Anyone knows what can i do?

```html
<body>
  <div id="app" class="flex-container">
    <nav class="navbar default-layout p-0 fixed-top d-flex flex-row" style="height: 63px;">
      <select id="region" onchange="initProcess();" style="position:absolute;background:#eaeaea;">
      </select>
      <div style="width: calc(100% - 74px); padding-left: 74px; left: 0; text-align: center; color: #fff">
        <img src="images/co-logo.png" style="width: 100px; margin-top: -6px">
        <h4>Dashboards</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-menu-wrapper d-flex align-items-right">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right d-lg-none align-self-right" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                    <span class="mdi mdi-menu"></span>
                </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:red"></div>
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:blue"></div>
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
    <div class="flex-item" style="background-color:grey"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily add padding-top css property equals to height of the navbar. in your case it'll be:

```
.flex-container {
     padding-top: 63px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the navbar is set to `position:fixed`, it ignores the normal flow of elements. Other elements align below it because of this. In this case just add `margin-top: 63px;` to the first element and you're good to go(the `63px` is the exact same height your navbar is).

Answer (score 1):

This css will work in your case:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: purple;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
.flex-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
.flex-container .flex-item:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```